# Proof Validation - Probability Theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Question Description:**

We consider opinion polling in a population of size $N$. Each individual in the population has one of two possible opinions - either YES or NO. We say that the population has reached consensus if all individuals have the same opinion – i.e., under consensus, everyone in the population is either YES or everyone is NO. Till consensus is reached, we update the opinions as follows : we pick an individual uniformly at random from the population, and update his/her opinion to YES with probability $p$, or to NO with probability $1 − p$. Calculate the probability that, when consensus is reached, everyone has opinion YES.

---

**My Thought:**

I was thinking of using the combination numbers.

Pr(when consensus is reach, everyone has opinion YES)$=\prod_{i=0}^{N-1} {N-i\choose 1}p^N=Cp^N,$ where $C:=\prod_{i=0}^{N-1} {N-i\choose 1}.$

Is my answer correct? I feel like my attempt is too simple to work out the problem, which should have something to do with fancy probabilistic theory.

Thanks for help.

Comment: This is a random walk problem in disguise.

Comment: Hmmm, but a YES can not offset a NO… I mean we may not identify YES with 1 and NO with -1 to adapt to the random walk problem.

Comment: If $p=1$ the answer is obviously $1$, but you get something greater than $1$, impossibly.

Comment: @lulu Yea I agree with you.

Comment: Perhaps it will help if you work with states, indexed, say, by the number of Yes votes.  At first glance, state $S(i)$ can go to $S(i\pm 1)$ or it can stay at $S(i)$.  However, we can disregard the latter case.  We don't care how long it takes that state to move, we only care about the transitions that actually move it. So, compute the probabilities that $S(i)$ moves to $S(i\pm 1)$ when it first moves and recast the problem in terms of those transition probabilities.

Comment: @SamWong are you familiar with martingale theory?

Comment: @lulu I see. Have we already assumed that we can update opinions infinitely many times? If so, then from state $S(i)$ to $S(i+1)$, there countably infinitely many cases and we can calculate the probability of each case and then sum them up. Finally we add up all the probabilities from $S(i)$ to $S(i+1)$ for $i=0, 1, 2, …, N-1$ to get the desired probability.

Comment: @Snoop I only know some basic definitions and elementary properties.

Comment: I assume you can keep going until you have reached unanimity.  And don't worry about all the possible paths from $S(i)$ to $S(i\pm 1)$...the set up just requires you to compute the two  transition probabilities.  Note that these will, of course, depend on $i$.

Comment: @SamWong nevermind, this problem seems actually different than what I initially thought